# How to encrypt a single folder on my external hard drive?

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption

I'd like to encrypt a single folder in my external hard drive. Which GUI software should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider TrueCrypt.  There is a nice GUI, I believe.

---

In the meantime since the original writing in 2011, a few things have changed. TrueCrypt is no longer available as the project maintainers have suddenly declared the software as insecure. A security audit was performed and a fork of the software, now called [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html), has continued the development.

Comment: I actually used TrueCrypt and there is indeed a nice GUI. Worked fine!

Comment: @htorque: true, but I rather state that I am not sure than pretending that I know everything. I could have posted nothing, but I thought that it might help the asking person.

Answer (score 6):

I have used `encfs` for such a task.

It allows you to mount the folder to encrypt onto an empty folder. After that, everything you put under the mount point will be encrypted. When you unmount the folder, your crypted data is no longer visible, until you mount it again.

There is also a GUI, in the package `cryptkeeper`.

Answer (score 3):

The strongest and the best solution for me is to encrypt a folder with [pgp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy). See these tutorials for more information:

[Create Encrypted Files and Folders in Ubuntu 10.04/10.10 Maverick Meerkat with Seahorse](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/10/create-encrypted-files-folders-ubuntu-10-0410-10-maverick-meerkat-seahorse/)

[HOWTO: Encrypted directory with EncFS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=148600)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cryptmount easily to create an encrypted file system and mount it on a folder. Although its a command line utility but its easy to use. I am not aware if there is GUI frontend available for it. You can find more details on using it [here](http://binwaheed.blogspot.com/2008/09/portable-encrypted-filesystem-using.html)