# How can I password-protect a folder?

Tags: encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt a single folder on my external hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34429/how-to-encrypt-a-single-folder-on-my-external-hard-drive)

I'd like to place private documents into a password-protected folder.

It's important that
* even if someone is using my account they can't access the folder
* the folder be encrypted

Answer (score 2):

Use truecrypt, its solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create an archive and put it on password.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. this will come in handy, but for a more long term solution there are a few problems with this method.