# Secure and portable to encrypt a USB drive

Tags: security, encryption

How to encrypt contents of a USB drive on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop and then be able to decrypt it on any other Linux Machine?

I see [Truecrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) being offered as a solution to an [earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34429/how-to-encrypt-a-single-folder-on-my-external-hard-drive) on this site. But, the Truecrypt landing page shows following warning now:

> WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed
>   security issues

Is there an alternative free open source disk encryption software that may be used across various Linux systems?

Comment: If you do a Full install of Ubuntu to USB drive, you will be given the option to encrypt the home folder. This can be used to transfer encrypted data from one computer to another. Have not managed to get full disk encryption working with a flash drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VeraCrypt is a good alternative. It's a fork of TrueCrypt which is still maintained. It's not in the ubuntu repos, but you can download and install it at their [website](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html).

There are other ways to do this as well, including LUKS and encrypted file systems, but VeraCrypt is simple and effective.